# How can I create a signed URL for Google Cloud Storage with a project level service account?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

For every Google Compute instance, there is a default service account like this:

1234567890123-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

I can create my instance with the proper scope (i.e. https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control) and use this account to make API requests.

On this page: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts it says:

> Every project has a service account associated with it, which may be used for authentication and to enable advanced features such as Signed URLs and browser uploads using POST.

This implies that I can use this service account to created Signed URLs.  However, I have no idea how to create a signed URL with this service account since I can't seem to get the private key (.p12 file) associated with this account.

I can create a new, separate service account from the developer console, and that has the option of downloading a .p12 file for signing, but the project level service accounts do not appear under the "APIs and auth / Credentials" section.  I can see them under "Project / Permissions", but I can't do anything with them there.

Am I missing some other way to retrieve the private key for these default accounts, or is there no way to sign urls when using them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use p12 key of any of your service account while you're authenticated through your main account or a GCE service account or other services accounts that have appropriate permissions on the bucket and the file.

In this case, just create a service account download p12 key and use the following command to sign your URL:

$ gsutil signurl -d 10m privatekey.p12 gs://bucket/foo

Though you can authenticate using different service account using the following command:

gcloud auth activate-service-account service-account-email --key-file key.p12

You can list and switch your accounts using these commands:

$ gcloud auth list 
$ gcloud config set account

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using a second service account as suggested.  I thought there might be a way to use the existing pre-configured account, but if that is not the case, then this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: When you create a VM instance, by default the active service account is GCE service account that is listed on APIs & Auth -> Credentials of your project in the Developers Console. You can run gsutil command and it will use this service account to do the job. However since this pre-configured GCE service account does not have p12 key you have to use a different service account’s key to sign URLs. In this case, devstorage.full_control has to be configured for the GCE service account to have fully access to Cloud Storage bucket and objects to sign URLs.

Comment: is it possible to pass an additional query parameter that I need in the signed URL?